# Fix fudge that is too rich

Tags: fudge, cocoa

I've made some fudge from a paleo recipe using almond butter, coconut oil, honey and cocoa powder.

Following this recipe, I find the fudge far too rich to eat -- the cocoa requirement was for 6 tablespoons in the recipe, but I feel this is too much. Is there any way I can now correct this **after** I've formed the fudge and refrigerated it?

I'm loathe to bin it all, but figure I can let it soften again and tweak it somehow.

Comment: What is your definition of "too rich"? Most people I've met seem to use the word either to denote food with too much fat, or food with too much sugar. You seem to use it for a strong chocolate flavor?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest remedy is just to cut it into smaller pieces, so you don't feel overwhelmed when eating a single piece.

Cocoa powder is slightly bitter, so cutting it back might actually make the fudge taste sweeter.  Instead, you could take small portions of the the fudge, roll them into balls, then roll them in cocoa powder to make chocolate truffles.

Comment: Yes!  Please tweak, don't bin!

Answer (score 0):

Efforts to "fix" the fudge aren't likely to succeed. The fudge making process is a one way trip: you cook sugar syrup to a certain temperature, and then add butter and volatile flavorings like vanilla as it cools. At a certain point you beat the fudge, which causes the sugar to form zillions of very small crystals instead of fewer larger ones, and this is where the fudge gets that smooth fudgy texture. To fix your fudge, you'd need to heat it again so that you could dilute the cocoa with something -- more sugar perhaps. But even if you heated it back to the point where the crystals would melt again, you won't get the same crystallization process happening because you've already added the butter.

Your best bet is to start over. Give the first batch to someone who likes intense chocolate, or just throw it out. The cost of the ingredients is small and your time is valuable -- don't bother trying to fix the result of an irreversible process.

Comment: I agree that making fudge is a one-way process. But the "too rich", so concentrated, fudge can be probably used to make something else. Maybe dissolve it in cream and make a pudding with it, or similar.

Comment: Perhaps it could be turned into hot fudge sauce for ice cream.